# Using asyncio.create_subprocess_shell within Django channels Consumer

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-asyncio, django-channels

Whenever a client (i.e. consumer) connects to my Django server, I want to execute a command in the command line, and then print the return code of the command:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import asyncio

class Consumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def do_command(self):
        process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell('pwd', stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
        try:
            line = await asyncio.wait_for(process.stdout.readline(), 5)
            print("line is" + line.decode())
            print(process.returncode)
            # wait for process to finish so we can check the return code
            await asyncio.wait_for(process.wait(), 5)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print("process timed out!")
        else:
            print("process finished successfully!")
        finally:
            print(process.returncode)

    async def connect(self):
        asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(self.do_command())
        print("Finished scheduling do_command task")
```

When I run the above code, I get

```
Finished scheduling do_command task
line is /opt/working_dir/django
None
process timed out!
None
```

whenever a client connects to my server.

However, `process.returncode` is always `None`

Why is that? I need to know if the command succeeded or not.

The issue seems to be specifically with the `await process.wait`.
For some reason, the command never finishes executing (i.e. `process.returncode` is always `None`).

However, the following code works fine:

```
import asyncio
async def do_command():
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(cmd='pwd')
    await process.wait()
    print("Finished process.wait")
    print(process.returncode)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(do_command())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(task)
loop.close()
print("Finished Go Task")
```

returns:

```
/opt/working_dir/django
Finished process.wait
0
Finished Go Task
```

Comment: IN all probabality: the `sudo /bin/systemctl start ssh` command never finishes, and `await process.wait()` never returns. Are you certain that your Django server has `sudo` rights? What happens when you use [`await asyncio.wait_for(process.wait(), 30)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) to avoid waiting indefinitely?

Comment: Permissions is not the issue, I changed `create_subprocess_shell('sudo /bin/systemctl start ssh')` to `create_subprocess_shell('pwd')` and I get the same behavior.

Comment: I changed `await process.wait()` to `await asyncio.wait_for(process.wait(), 30)` and get the same behavior, `command has finished` is never printed, even after 30 seconds

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit about this: `await_for()` raises an exception when the timeout is reached, see the documentation. Do catch the raised [`TimeoutException`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.TimeoutError).

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters! However, I need the returncode from my create_subprocess_shell command. I updated my question above to better illustrate this.

Comment: If the command *timed out* then there is no return code. How are you running your Django server, exactly? Perhaps there is no valid current working directory. Can you try to log a bog-standard [`subprocess.run('pwd', shell=True)` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) outside of the event loo, but in the Django process? `asyncio` ultimately just uses `subprocess.Popen()` under the hood, and the problem is with the child process that's been started now hanging

Comment: One possibility: SInce you don't redirect `stdout` of the child process, the output of the `pwd` command goes to the `stdout` of the django process, and perhaps *that* filehandle is not accepting data. So `pwd`'s write to stdout would then be hanging. Adding `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to the `.run()` call (or `stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE` to the `create_subprocess_shell` call) should at least direct the output to a pipe connected to the Django end, where you can then read that data (for the asyncio version, do first `await process.stdout.read()` before waiting).

Comment: The pwd command itself succeeds, I updated my question to show that it correctly prints the current directory by piping the stdout as @MartijnPieters suggested and then reading stdout. However, my django server still times out on the `process.wait()` and `process.returncode` is always `None`

Comment: Right, so we eliminated blocking on stdout, but the shell process still hangs. What info can you get from the OS? Is the PID state visible in `ps -fA`? Does `lsof` reveal anything about the process? Can you use `strace` to see what if anything the process is doing?